# Create new command using Minecraft Forge, and generating a block when the command is executed

Tags: server, command, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I created a Command class that extends CommandBase and I want it to spawn a block that I created and called "zero" at the position where the player is looking. Here is the code that I wrote, but it doesn't do anything. I hope someone can help, and thank you in advance.[Command execution code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnrz4.png)
[event handler code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt4QR.png)

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: please include code directly in your question. + provide at least a link to the CommandBase API documentation. + explain what means  "doesn't do anything" (i.e. is your code called ?) + add logs to really see what's happening + use a debugger

Comment: I cannot include the codes directly in the question, because it is beyond the number of characters allowed. That is why I have included two images, and you can see them by clicking on "Command execution code" and "event handler code".
Concerning the CommandBase API, here is a github page that explains it https://github.com/QuickStartEssentials/QuickStart/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/co/drnaylor/minecraft/quickstart/internal/CommandBase.java
What I meant by "doesnt do anything" is that it doesnt show the block, so the game is still the same, and no block is added to the position i want.

Comment: Here is another link about the API: http://apiwave.com/java/api/net.minecraft.command.CommandBase

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to set the block then why are you adding a new world gen? Just use world.setBlock (or setBlockState in newer versions).
The player lookvec is not at the block you are looking at, but exactly 1 block in front of your face. So if you are looking at an angle it will be spawned in the same space as your head (potentially suffocating you).

Answer (score 0):

When running the command, you could always check the players hitVec. Get the coords of the block being looked at, and ask the world to set the block using the coordinates gathered.

Comment: If only I knew how to delete comments, Alpvax said it much better than I could explain. :-)